# Exception of type 'MS.Internal.Validate+ValidationFailure' was thrown

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5

I am using VS 2010 SP1
I am having this error after installed the .Net Framework 4.5 developer preview:

While editing a WPF Application, appears the error:

```
Exception of type 'MS.Internal.Validate+ValidationFailure' was thrown.
```

Then I uninstalled the .Net 4.5
and now Visual Studio 2010 quit working... now gives me an "unknown error" dialogue when launched

Does somebody also have this issue, or can tell a solution?

Comment: And what is your [question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)?

Comment: I have same error here in my situation with Visual Studio 2010 and WPF application, updated to newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled .net 4.5
then VS stopped working
then i runned VS 2010 Repair mode
then the installer runned, at some percentage it gave an error
then i closed it, and opened VS 2010, normally.